# Is it possible to bind a socket with NIC Queue?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, nic

when i open a new socket linux system automatically bind it to a NIC queu. Currently i have two sockets and i want to bind them to two different NIC queues. My question is

1)Is it possible to bind sockets to nic queue programmatically  or using some linux command.

2)If so please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: With the term "queue" you mean interface? For example, if you have 2 interfaces with IPs 192.168.1.1 and 10.0.0.1, you want to bind the one socket to the interface with IP 192.168.1.1 and the other socket to the interface with IP 10.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i open a new socket linux system automatically bind it to a NIC queue.

No it doesn't. Either you `bind()` it to a local IP address or the system does it for you automatically when you connect the socket, in the case of TCP, or first send from it, in the case of UDP.

> Currently i have two sockets and i want to bind them to two different NIC queues. My question is
>
> 1)Is it possible to bind sockets to nic queue programmatically or using some linux command.

Yes, see above.

> 2)If so please guide me in the right direction.

See above.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of TCP as EJP mentioned, you can `bind()` the socket to a specific network interface, by specifying its IP address to the `sockaddr_in` structure.

For example:

```cpp
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in sin;

if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1) {
    perror("opening TCP listening socket");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
/* For this example, we bind the socket to port 10080 */
sin.sin_port = htons(10080);
/* Bind to a specific interface with IP 192.168.1.1 */
if (inet_aton("192.168.1.1", &sin.sin_addr) == 0) {
    printf("Invalid IP address");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
        == -1) {
    perror("TCP bind");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

After that you can see that your program has bind the socket to the specified interface using the command:
`netstat -tpn`